# Trigger @OneToMany lazy fetch

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, eclipselink

I have an `ExampleRequest` entity that can optionally have one or more `ExampleRequestYear`. It's currently configured this way (unrelated fields and gettters/setters omitted for brevity, please let me know if you need anything else):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EXAMPLE_REQUEST")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "EXAMPLE_REQUEST_ID_SEQ", sequenceName = "EXAMPLE_REQUEST_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@Cacheable(false)
public class ExampleRequest implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "EXAMPLE_REQUEST_ID_SEQ")
    @Column(name="EXAMPLE_REQUEST_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long exampleRequestId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "exampleRequest")
    private List<ExampleRequestYear> exampleRequestYearList;

    public ExampleRequest() {
    }

    public List<ExampleRequestYear> getExampleRequestYearList() {
        if(this.exampleRequestYearList == null){
            this.exampleRequestYearList = new ArrayList<ExampleRequestYear>();
        }
        return this.exampleRequestYearList;
    }

    public void setExampleRequestYearList(List<ExampleRequestYear> exampleRequestYearList) {
        this.exampleRequestYearList = exampleRequestYearList;
    }

    public ExampleRequestYear addExampleRequestYear(ExampleRequestYear exampleRequestYear) {
        getExampleRequestYearList().add(exampleRequestYear);
        exampleRequestYear.setExampleRequest(this);
        return exampleRequestYear;
    }

    public ExampleRequestYear removeExampleRequestYear(ExampleRequestYear exampleRequestYear) {
        getExampleRequestYearList().remove(exampleRequestYear);
        exampleRequestYear.setExampleRequest(null);
        return exampleRequestYear;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "EXAMPLE_REQUEST_YEAR")
@IdClass(ExampleRequestYearPK.class)
public class ExampleRequestYear implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer year;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "EXAMPLE_REQUEST_ID", referencedColumnName = "EXAMPLE_REQUEST_ID")
    private ExampleRequest exampleRequest;

    public ExampleRequestYear() {
    }

    public void setExampleRequest(ExampleRequest exampleRequest) {
        this.exampleRequest = exampleRequest;
    }

    public ExampleRequest getExampleRequest() {
        return exampleRequest;
    }
}
```

Part of the code was auto-generated by the IDE and I'm still wrapping my head around JPA so there're probably design mistakes all around.

My app works (apparently) when I create a new `ExampleRequest`:

```
ExampleRequest exampleRequest = new ExampleRequest();
ExampleRequestYear exampleRequestYear = new ExampleRequestYear(2020);
request.addExampleRequestYear(exampleRequestYear);
```

However, I can't figure out how to edit an existing `ExampleRequest` because I'm unsure on how I'm meant to retrieve the linked entities. According to articles I've read, lazy fetching should be automatic, yet when I try this:

```
ExampleRequest exampleRequest = employeeRequestsController.getExampleRequestById(123);
System.out.println(exampleRequest.getExampleRequestYearList().size());
```

... I get a null pointer exception upon `.size()` because the getter runs but neither initialises an empty list, nor retrieves items from DB:

```
public List<ExampleRequestYear> getExampleRequestYearList() {
    if(this.exampleRequestYearList == null){
        // Field is null and conditional is entered
        this.exampleRequestYearList = new ArrayList<ExampleRequestYear>();
        // After initialisation, field is still null!
    }
    return this.exampleRequestYearList;
}
```

Also, switch to `FetchType.EAGER` solves this particular problem entirely. What am I missing?

---

Further details regarding app design. The `Resource` classes that handle HTTP requests interact with a set of `Controller` classes like this:

```
@Stateless(name = "ISomeActionController", mappedName = "ISomeActionController")
public class SomeActionController implements ISomeActionController {
    @EJB
    private IFooDAO fooDao;

    @EJB
    private IBarDAO barDao;

    @Override
    public ExampleRequest getExampleRequestById(Long exampleRequestId) {
        return fooDao.getEntityById(exampleRequestId);
    }
}
```

It's in the DAO classes where `EntityManager` is injected an used:

```
@Local
public interface IGenericDAO<T> {
    public T persistEntity(T o);
    public T persistEntityCommit(T o);
    public void removeEntity(T o);
    public void removeEntity(long id);
    public T mergeEntity(T o);
    public List<T> getEntitiesFindAll();
    public List<T> getEntitiesFindAllActive();
    public T getEntityById(Object id);
}

public interface IFooDAO extends IGenericDAO<ExampleRequest> {
    public void flushDAO();
    public ExampleRequest getExampleRequestById(Long exampleRequestId);
}

@Stateless(name = "IFooDAO", mappedName = "IFooDAO")
public class FooDAO extends GenericDAO<ExampleRequest> implements IFooDAO {
    public FooDAO() {
        super(ExampleRequest.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void flushDAO(){
        em.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public ExampleRequest getExampleRequestById(Long exampleRequestId){
        String sql = "...";
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql, ExampleRequest.class);
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I would start investigating why the `this.exampleRequestYearList == null` condition is fulfilled but the field is "null" afterwards because that has nothing to do with JPA and strikes me as highly suspicious. When you load an entity from the database the properties denoted by collection-annotations should all be objects of "PersistentBag" or similar.

Comment: I get my values fetched if I invoke `.size()` inside `employeeRequestsController.getExampleRequestById()`, but that's essentially the same as eager-loading them. In either case, I eventually get NullPointerException much later at `ExampleRequestYear.pcCopyKeyFieldsFromObjectId(ExampleRequestYear.java)` so I suspect this project does something terribly wrong somewhere else and I don't have the faintest clue of where to even look 

Comment: What is `ExampleRequestYear.pcCopyKeyFieldsFromObjectId(ExampleRequestYear.java)`?

Comment: @Smutje I've no idea, it's some internal method of my JPA implementation. The core issue seems to be that any fancy JPA feature doesn't work outside the inner DAO classes where `EntityManager` is injected and used, and I don't think the code I've shared has anything to do with that.

Comment: Are your "inner DAO classes" EJB or do you create transactions manually?

Comment: @Smutje `pcCopyKeyFieldsFromObjectId()` was a red herring (it triggered because I was adding two `ExampleRequestYear` with the same PK). App seems to use EJB, I've added that to the question.

Comment: "Also, switch to FetchType.EAGER solves this particular problem entirely. What am I missing?" - because you are most certainly outside of a transaction by the time you call the getter and so JPA can not load the collection without an active transaction.

Comment: @Smutje Thank you, you've been extremely helpful. I think now I have a much better understanding of the big picture. I'm unsure about how to get a proper fix since transactions are handled by non-application code for the most part, but that's certainly a different issue and beyond this question's scope. To sum up: 1) Yes, that's how it's done 2) It isn't working for me because there's no active transaction any more.

Comment: It won't be the transactional bounds - EclipseLInk doesn't care about transactions when loading lazy relationships - the problem will be with serialization. This is being serialized to the client which calls 'get' on the lazy relationship, but serialization wipes out the EM context and anything that would tell your application that the values just weren't loaded. You will need to trigger the values you want before serialization (i.e. in getExampleRequestById just call getExampleRequestYearList().size()) , or write your own serialization methods to ensure they are included.

Comment: @Chris When does serialisation happen?